# What am I doing wrong with weights?

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I'm getting this:

[image: Inverted weights]

But I have this layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

So, as you can see, I want the Button to be 30% and the EditText to be 70%

Two questions:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Should I use weights? because in a tablet the 30% might be too much for the button (maybe I should use an absolute value for the button?)

Comment: is this the complete xml, do you have any margins for the parent of linearlayout, for tablets keep a different xml file, based on screen size

Comment: Add weightSum="1.0" to your LinearLayout, and the children should have layout_width="0dp" for assurance.

Comment: no is not the complete XML... the linearlayout showed here (horizontal) is child of another linearlayout (vertical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using weight, either `layout_height` or `layout_width` must be 0dp, depending which axis you want to stretch
In your example you should set `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: If I want to stretch horizontal I have to set layout_width 0dp?

Comment: yes , if stretch is horizontal, the width should be 0dp , and if the stretch is vertical, the height should be 0dp